# Pass raw html from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass raw html from view to controller. Iam trying to do it with jquery ajax request. Everything is ok until object with raw html passes to controller. What is my mistake?
Here is my model, controller and jquery.

Thank you.

Model

```
public class NewsEditionModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string SubTitle { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult AddText(NewsEditionModel obj)
    {
        var news = new News();
        try
        {
            news.Text = obj.Text;
            news.PublishDate = DateTime.Now;
            news.Title = obj.Title;
            var repository = new Repository();
            var success = repository.AddNews(news, User.Identity.Name);
            return Json(new {data = success});
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

Jquery

```
function submitForm() {
    var text = ste.getContent();
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var obj1 = JSON.stringify({ Text: text, Title: title, SubTitle: "" });
    var obj = $.parseJSON(obj1);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        content: "application/json",
        data: {obj: obj},
        url: '@Url.Action("AddText", "News")',
        success: function (res) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add  `<ValidateInput(False)> _` to your contoller post req.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this example

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '@Url.Action("AddText", "News")',
    data: {obj: JSON.stringify({ Text: text, Title: title, SubTitle: "" })},
   contentType: 'application/json',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (data) { alert(data); }
});
```

Comment: It's hard to say even with debugger. But I can say that obj in controller is not initialized. But if I use example of my own, model is initialized, but properties(Text etc) are setted to true.

Comment: Using your example I have javascript error. Think it's because of html tags in data.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: yes you have server error please check header request in chrome and response what is exactly your error.

Comment: Here is my obj:{"Text":"<b><u>dasdad</u></b>","Title":"","SubTitle":""}.

Comment: And error: Detected a potentially dangerous value Request.Form, received from the client (obj = "{" Text ":" <b> <u> dasdad </ u> </ b> ... ").

Comment: please check your header with developer tools in chrome or check with firebug

Comment: Finally, I've found the correct answer. I've just added ValidateInput attribute and setted it to false.

Answer (score 1):

I guess instead of this:

```
data: {obj: obj},
```

you should do it like this:

```
data: {obj: JSON.stringify({ Text: text, Title: title, SubTitle: "" })},
```